# What makes the bitrate of dash stream output low as compared to bitrate of input mp4 video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, ffprobe, bitrate

I used ffmpeg to convert bbb.mp4 to dash stream. I used the ffprobe to get the bitrates of input and output (shown below)
For the same resolution video 1920x1080 input has bit rate 2998 kb/s where as output has bitate of 20 kb/s.
My profile is set to "-b:v:0 200K -s:v:0 640x360 -b:v:1 600K -s:v:1 852x480 -b:v:2 4000K -s:v:2 1920x1080".
I am trying to understand what determines the output bit rate for the dash stream?
Why does my output different from the input profile set in ffmpeg command

Input video stream - bbb.mp4

```
'''  Duration: 00:10:34.53, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3481 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2998 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30k tbn, 60 tbc (default)'''
```

Output:

```
'''  Duration: 00:10:34.60, start: 630.000000, bitrate: 20 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 20 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)

    major_brand     : iso5
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: iso5iso6mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.42.100
  Duration: 00:10:34.60, start: 630.000000, bitrate: 4 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 852x480 [SAR 640:639 DAR 16:9], 4 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)

    major_brand     : iso5
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: iso5iso6mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.42.100
  Duration: 00:10:34.60, start: 630.000000, bitrate: 1 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
'''
```

I tried to look in ffprobe documentation I could not find the definition of the bit_rate field output in ffprobe.

Can you please help me to understand this?